# How to pass selected value of an option

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to call a method on an option when the user selects it.

In my code behind for now I have:

```
protected void OnItemClick(AddressDTO address)
{
    if (SelectedAddresses.AddressList.Contains(address))
    { 
        SelectedAddresses.AddressList.Remove(address); 
    }
    else
    {
        SelectedAddresses.AddressList.Add(address);
    }
}
```

then in my page:

```
<select multiple>
    @foreach (var Address in AllVendorAddresses.AddressList)
    {
        <option value="@Address.Id" @onclick="@(()=>OnItemClick(@Address))" >@Address.AddressLine1 @Address.AddressLine2 @Address.Town</option>
    }
</select>
```

My trouble is that the event will obviously trigger when each option is clicked, So I need to be able to determine in my code behind if the option was selected or de-selected. This works fine for single select, but get's into trouble on a multi-select.

Does anyone know how I might do this?

Comment: Please describe what's the actual error you are facing? You should not need the `@` before `Address` since you've already escaped into C#: `@(() => OnItemClick(Address))"`

Comment: @Mushroomator I dont have an error I want to know how I can also pass the selected value

Comment: You already pass the `Address` to `OnItemClick` so you should be able to access the `Id` which you have defined as the value. You could of course also just pass the Id or use the DOM event to get the selected value, but that seems more complicated than necessary.

Comment: @Mushroomator yes, that would be fine on a single select, but this needs to be multi-select.

Comment: Maybe check out [docs on `<InputSelect>` with multiple options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-and-input-components?view=aspnetcore-7.0#multiple-option-selection-with-the-inputselect-component).

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the standard select input control.  There are contradictions between what the control believes is selected and what any list or dictionary may set the option list to.  You may need to build a component from the bottom up to achieve what you want - or look for one from a component supplier.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend making a `Dictionary` using all your addresses for the keys, and bools for the values, which will represent the selection state for that address.

Then when you want to see the state of the address, it's simple:

**(In initialization)**

```
var AddressSelectionDictionary = AllVendorAddresses.AddressList
                                 .ToDictionary(va => s, va => false);
```

**(When you want to check it, including in markup loops)**

```
bool IsSelected = AddressSelectionDictionary[Address];
```

**(And to change it, very simple)**

```
<option @onclick="@(()=>AddressSelectionDictionary[Address]=!AddressSelectionDictionary[Address])"> . . . </option>
```

Comment: This has the same issue as my original. If I multiselect, then select a single thus undoing the multiselect, it only toggles the existing value selected, not all values. e.g. 10 in the list I click the first one hold shift and select more, they all are ok, I then stop holding shift and press one of the values, the original selections stay.

Comment: Your OP said nothing about making a website act like Windows.  Don't do that-- most people on the web use phones, and phones do not use the shift-key in this way.